# JS Как заблокировать переключатель (input) если не выбран предыдущий чекбокс

Tags: javascript

Объясните как сделать и как оно работает. Заранее благодарю!!!

Написать условия: 
Если переключатель с id="adapt "не выбран,
заблокировать переключатель( input id=”mobileTemplates”)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
    var check1 = document.getElementById('adapt'); // Получаем элемент по ID
    if (check1.checked == false){ // Если элемент не выбран, то
        document.getElementById('mobileTemplates').disabled = true; // Элементу с ID mobileTemplates проставляем свойство disabled =true
    }
    check1.onchange = function () { // Отслеживаем изменение чекбокса
        if (check1.checked == false){ // Если элемент не выбран, то
            document.getElementById('mobileTemplates').disabled = true; // Элементу с ID mobileTemplates проставляем свойство disabled =true
        } else {
            document.getElementById('mobileTemplates').disabled = false; // Если выбран, то ставим свойсто disabled false
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="adapt" />
<input type="checkbox" id="mobileTemplates" />
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function enableTemplates() {
  if (!document.getElementById('adapt').checked)
    document.getElementById('mobileTemplates').setAttribute("disabled", "true");
  else
    document.getElementById('mobileTemplates').removeAttribute("disabled");
}
enableTemplates();
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="adapt" onchange="enableTemplates()" />
<input type="checkbox" id="mobileTemplates" />
```